# Excel Formula to Auto Calculate the 4 Week Moving Average

Tags: excel, data-analysis, moving-average

[image]

Please see the image uploaded to the thread. I will keep adding data every week to the table's corresponding columns. The 4 weeks moving average has to be calculated automatically on the cell above the the column header.

The formula also has to ignore weeks with no values or zero when calculating the moving average.

Appreciate all the help I can get

I can't seem to get the formula to find the moving average of the last 4 weeks.

```
IFERROR(AVERAGEIF(OFFSET(Table32[[#Headers],[LAMINATED PANEL (SQFT/HR)]],COUNT(Table32[LAMINATED PANEL (SQFT/HR)]),0,-4),"<>0"),0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Base formula:

```
=TAKE(LET(a,D5:D16,b,FILTER(a,a<>0),MAKEARRAY(ROWS(b), 1, LAMBDA(r,c, AVERAGE(TAKE(INDEX(b, SEQUENCE(r), 1), -4))))),-1)
```

All formula:

```
=LET(
data, C5:E16,
p, TAKE(data, , 1),
l, CHOOSECOLS(data, 2),
s, TAKE(data, , -1),
p4wa,  TAKE(LET(a,p,b,FILTER(a,a<>0),MAKEARRAY(ROWS(b), 1, LAMBDA(r,c, AVERAGE(TAKE(INDEX(b, SEQUENCE(r), 1), -4))))),-1),
l4wa,  TAKE(LET(a,l,b,FILTER(a,a<>0),MAKEARRAY(ROWS(b), 1, LAMBDA(r,c, AVERAGE(TAKE(INDEX(b, SEQUENCE(r), 1), -4))))),-1),
s4wa,  TAKE(LET(a,s,b,FILTER(a,a<>0),MAKEARRAY(ROWS(b), 1, LAMBDA(r,c, AVERAGE(TAKE(INDEX(b, SEQUENCE(r), 1), -4))))),-1),
final, HSTACK(p4wa,l4wa,s4wa),
final
)
```

[image]

Comment: I want the formula to ignore the weeks with no data when considering the 4 weeks moving average.

Comment: I would appreciate if there's a way to include in the formula to exclude the weeks with no production (Zero) data. Thank you!

Comment: Edited the Base and All formulas, with updated picture too.

Answer (score 1):

This formula spills the intended results in my sheet.

=BYCOL(D4:F10000,LAMBDA(c,AVERAGE(TAKE(FILTER(INDEX(c,1):INDEX(c,LARGE(IF(c<>"",
ROW(c)-3),1)),ISNUMBER(INDEX(c,1):INDEX(c,LARGE(IF(c<>"",ROW(c)-3),1)))),-4))))

[image: Excel Formula to Auto Calculate the 4 Week Moving Average]